# How to exclude few number from MVC RangeAttribute c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a range attribute with `Range(0, 999)`. I would like to exclude 1,2 from `Range` attribute. How can I do that?

I need to exclude 1,2 from this range

```
Range(0, 999, ErrorMessageResourceName = "NumberRange", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))
```

Comment: Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Where(x => (x != 1) && (x != 2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue

```
[RegularExpression("^[0 3-9]*$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "NumbersAllowed", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]      

   [Range(0, 999, ErrorMessageResourceName = "NumberRange", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always create custom validation attribute and use that in your model

```
public class CustomRangeAttribute: ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private double _MinValue, _MaxValue

    public CustomRangeAttribute(double min, double max, Func<string> errorMessageAccessor) : base(errorMessageAccessor)
    {
        _MinValue = min;
        _MaxValue = max;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        double val = (double)value;
        return val >= _MinValue && val <= _MaxValue;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessage, _MinValue, _MaxValue);
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "futuredate"
        };
    }
}
```

To use this in Model just add attribute at the top

```
[CustomRange(3, 45)]
```